# how to convert text file to dictionary in python wtih same key

Tags: python

I wonder how can i convert this text file:

```
Score 2
Score 1
Score 3
Score 21
```

to a dictionary which would look like this: {'Score': '2', 'Score': '1', 'Score': '3', 'Score': '21'}.
Because of the fact that the key name is the same this code:

```
a_dictionary = {}
a_file = open("score.txt")
for line in a_file:
    key, value = line.split()


    a_dictionary[key] = value

print(a_dictionary)
```

prints only the last dict `{'Score': '21'}`

Comment: The task is not well defined. Dictionary holds different keys and cannot hold the same key multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a dictonary where multiple keys are the same, in your example I would go with an array.

```
a_array = []
for line in a_file:
    a_array.append(line.split(" ")[1])

print(str(a_array))
```

Then you can access the respective line with `a_array[line_number]`

Comment: Did you mean: `a_array = [line.split(" ")[1] for line in a_file]; print(a_array)`?

Comment: @quamrana Yes, that would be the compact way ;-)